# Calculate score based on weight in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The idea is to sort rows based on values, so that the row with maximum 1s will get highest score, which I will use later to `sort_values` with `ascending=False`... It is also called weighed sum...

The dataframe is as follows:

```
    ID  SINNOUVEAU  PERTETOTAL  CHANGGARAN  SOCLOCATIO  SINISAMEDI  NOMASCONDU   INIREPET
0    1           1           1           0           0           0           1          0
1    1           0           1           0           0           0           1          0
2    1           1           0           1           0           0           1          0
0    2           1           1           1           0           0           1          0
1    2           0           1           0           0           0           1          0
2    2           1           0           1           0           0           1          0
```

The weights are all 1 except for CHANGGARAN which will be set to 2.

This is an example of the first row for the score to be calculated:
`1x1 + 1x1 + 0x2 + 0x1 + 0x1 + 1x1 + 0x1=3`

At the end this is the expected scores before sorting:

```
    ID  SINNOUVEAU  PERTETOTAL  CHANGGARAN  SOCLOCATIO  SINISAMEDI  NOMASCONDU   INIREPET  SCORE
0    1           1           1           0           0           0           1          0  3
1    1           0           1           0           0           0           1          0  2
2    1           1           0           1           0           0           1          0  4
0    2           1           1           1           0           0           1          0  5
1    2           0           1           0           0           0           1          0  2
2    2           1           0           1           0           0           1          0  4
```

Thanks!

Comment: how is the 3rd row rank 4?

Comment: 1 + 2 + 1 because CHANGGARAN's weight is 2

Comment: renamed rank to score

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `replace` on a specific column, then compute the sum across columns.

```
# Drop "ID" first because it is not a part of the sum
df.replace({'CHANGGARAN': {1: 2}}).drop('ID', 1).sum(axis=1)

0    3
1    2
2    4
0    5
1    2
2    4
dtype: int64
```

Reassign the result to a column, then use it to sort the DataFrame:

```
df['SCORE'] = df.replace({'CHANGGARAN': {1: 2}}).drop('ID', 1).sum(axis=1)
df_sorted = df.sort_values('SCORE')
```

Comment: Also there is an ID so I should update my question... as I need the sum to happen for each groupby

Comment: @SabiriS ummm, it seems like `df.replace({'CHANGGARAN': {1: 2}}).drop('ID', 1).sum(axis=1)` returns the desired score output. Where does the `groupby` come in here?

Answer (score 2):

I feel like we can using `dot` here

```
a=np.ones(df.shape[1])
a[0]=0
a[3]=2
df.dot(a)
0    3.0
1    2.0
2    4.0
0    5.0
1    2.0
2    4.0
dtype: float64
#df['SCORE']=df.dot(a)
```